# Jenkins and playwright : Exit a job that stuck asking to enter ctrl+c command

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, playwright

I am running a job that execute playwright test in my jenkins pipeline, then it stuck when playwright finishes the test and output the result with ctrl+c required to exit. Do you know how I can get over it or any workaround script for that.[image: jenkins running playwright test stuck asking to enter ctrl+c]

Comment: Thanks it does solved it. I edit the reporter to never open as suggested in the answer. So I can still get the output of the test on jenkins, when it fails it directly mark the test as failure. Thanks